# Not sure how to deal with none-fixed XML data types

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I am reading in an XML file and using the data within it to create a new object and then set the objects properties with the read data using LINQ.

For example, a section of the XML looks like this:

```
<heat_index_string>NA</heat_index_string>
<heat_index_f>NA</heat_index_f>
<heat_index_c>NA</heat_index_c>
<windchill_string>NA</windchill_string>
<windchill_f>NA</windchill_f>
<windchill_c>NA</windchill_c>
<pressure_mb>1013</pressure_mb>
<pressure_in>29.92</pressure_in>
```

Normally these "NA"'s would be represented by a `double` (E.G: `public double HeatIndexC { get; set; }`) However if that data is not available from the service, then the service returns "NA". There is no other information elsewhere in the XML that gives a list of data that is or is not available.

I read the XML like this:

```
    var data = from i in weather.Descendants("current_observation")
               select new CurrentConditions
               {
                   HeatIndexC = (double)i.Element("heat_index_c"),
                   //Set other properties here
               };
```

As can be seen, this will work fine as long as the service returns a double but once it returns a string then it will cause an exception.

So, how do I approach this? My first thought was to create yet more properties for each section, like this:

```
public bool TemperatureAvaliable { get; set; };
```

Another idea I had was to *only* use string types, but this seems pretty inflexible and not idiomatic at all.

To be clear: I don't know how to deal with a service that sometimes returns doubles but also sometimes returns a string. Additionally, the service does not state when it will return a string or a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `Nullable<double>` (a.k.a. `double?`).  Then the question is: how do you convert "NA" to `double?`?  Here's one approach:

```
var data = from i in weather.Descendants("current_observation")
           select new CurrentConditions
           {
               HeatIndexC = ToNullableDouble(i.Element("heat_index_c")),
               //Set other properties here
           };

double? ToNullableDouble(object xml)
{
    if (xml == null)
        return null;

    if (xml is double)
        return (double?)xml;

    double value;
    return double.TryParse(xml.ToString(), out value) ? value : (double?)null;
}
```

You might also want to look explicitly for "NA" and then throw an exception if any unrecognized string appears, rather than silently dropping the unexpected data.

EDIT

I just noticed that XElement also defines this conversion operator, which is probably the better way to handle this:

```
var data = from i in weather.Descendants("current_observation")
       select new CurrentConditions
       {
           HeatIndexC = (double?)i.Element("heat_index_c"),
           //Set other properties here
       };
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, ToNullableDouble will return either a double or a null depending on if the value was a double or not?

Comment: @user9993 it will return a nullable double.  The value of the variable will be either null or the double value.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm new to C#, what is the purpose of the out keyword when using TryParse?

Comment: @user9993 you have to use it because the parameter is declared as an out parameter.  If you don't use it, the code won't compile.  This is to help the calling code keep sight of the fact that it is an out parameter.

Comment: @user9993 I just noticed that XElement supports a `(double?)` conversion directly, so you can probably fix your code just by adding a question mark.

Comment: I get an exception with your second way: "Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: @user9993 You can see the error recreated in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5fQIzy)

Comment: @user9993, phoog's original answer is an excellent one and handles a lot of possible errors.  Mine is simpler, bit easier to read (IMO ;) but both are excellent ways to handle your problem.

Comment: @user9993 that's because I made an incorrect assumption about how the `double?` conversion works -- I didn't think about the fact that it would throw an exception for `"NA"`.  So the first option would be the way to go, though now that I know more about the XElement type I would probably modify the ToNullableDouble method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of casting to a double, use `TryParse`.

I assumed a default value of 0 if the heatIndex didnt parse.  Using a nullable double might be a more suitable alternative.

```
double heatIndexC;
var data = from i in weather.Descendants("current_observation")  
    select new CurrentConditions
    {
    var HeatIndexC = double.TryParse(i.Element("heat_index_c")
                                      .Value, out heatIndexC) 
                                     ? heatIndexC : 0,
        //Set other properties here
    };
```

Edit: Fixed output of value.

### [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m8WmFL)

Comment: Does `Element` return a string?  If it does, the OP's code is broken, even though he says it works.

Comment: Excellent point, I'm sure it does.  There would be no way to cast from string to double.

Comment: Element returns an XElement object, which has lots of explicit conversion operators defined.  So your code is in fact broken, not the OP's :)

Comment: @phoog Fixed, with fiddle.